# Program "calculator" button for ahk

Tags: autohotkey, logitech

what name can I use for the Logitech button that appears on their keyboard that I'm using. I want to reprogram it in Autohotkey. I see it opens the calculator if you did not install the the proprietary software. Thanks!
e.g.

```
Calculator::  ;then some commands
Logitech:: ;then some commands
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I set my `Calc` key to launch Google Chrome with [AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/):

```
Launch_App2::
    Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the keyboard hook along with viewing the keyboard history.

The process for finding these keys is specified in the [documentation](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).

Comment: ...I ran a script with code:

    #InstallKeybdHook
    KeyHistory

and this showed me that the solution is:
SC121::